# Reading a blob field

Tags: blob

When I read with PDI 6.1 and the Table Input step of an informix table a blob field I have the error:

2023/04/14 09:57:35 - Table input 2.0 - **Couldn't get row from result set**
2023/04/14 09:57:35 - **Table input 2.0 -**
2023/04/14 09:57:35 - **Table input 2.0 - Unable to get value** 'String(56)' from database resultset, index 0
2023/04/14 09:57:35 - Table input 2.0 - **Blob not found**

**This causes error:**

select campo from tabla where campo2 = ?;

**This does not fail, but i do not get the complete string:**

select campo[1,4000] from tabla where campo2 = ?;